# Java, Dropbox : Get access token without copy pasting by user.

Tags: java, spring, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am working on a Spring-MVC  application and I would like to integrate Dropbox functionality into it. As I read the examples, I saw that there is some code which I can use. But this involves the user copy pasting the access token, which is not applicable in real world applications, plus I cannot find a way to set the redirect URL when authentication is complete. What changes should I make so the code does not need to copy pasted, but can be retrieved directly.

Code :

```
 public void connectToDropbox() {

        DbxAppInfo appInfo = new DbxAppInfo(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

        DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("JavaTutorial/1.0",
                Locale.getDefault().toString());

        DbxWebAuthNoRedirect webAuth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(config, appInfo);


        // Have the user sign in and authorize your app.
        String authorizeUrl = webAuth.start();
        System.out.println("1. Go to: " + authorizeUrl);
        System.out.println("2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first)");
// No, I dont want to copy the authorization code. 
        System.out.println("3. Copy the authorization code.");
        String code = null;
        try {
            code = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine().trim();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Controller code :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/logindropbox")
    public String loginIntoDropbox(){
        ConnectDropbox connectDropbox = new ConnectDropbox();
        connectDropbox.connectToDropbox();
        return "rediect:/dashboard";
    }
```

There was only one answer I could find on SO, but that was of no use. Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: you have found the solution? I have the same problem, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203308909-Dropbox-authentication-without-copy-pasting-the-access-token-manually-in-Java- ]

The [Dropbox Java Core SDK tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java) does use the flow where the user copies and pastes the authorization code manually. This is done using the provided `DbxWebAuthNoRedirect` class.

For apps where a redirect URI can be used to deliver the authorization code automatically, you'll want to use the `DbxWebAuth` class instead. The documentation has some sample code:

https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxWebAuth.html

There's also a "web-file-browser" sample app included with the [SDK download](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/java) that uses `DbxWebAuth`.

Comment: I will accept this answer, as it gives me what I requires, but I have already programmed it with REST authentication, so I don't need the data anymore, maybe other users who have this problem will be able to use it. I will later try the information when I get time.